# Apply even/odd style in MVC editor template for List<> model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, editortemplates, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to apply some odd/even style to rows of data rendered by a Razor editor template in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Here is some basic code of my possible **view**:

```
@model List<MyProject.Whatever>

@Html.EditorFor(Model)
```

And here the possible **editor template**:

```
@model MyProject.Whatever

<div class="@( AnIInAnEvenOrOddRow ? "even" : "odd" )">
  @Model.SomeData @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeTextToType)
</div>
```

Have anybody an idea how I can detect the even/odd situation from inside the editor template?

Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

I always interpret Rows of data `==` `@WebGrid` witch has already that feature included and you can easily [**implement paging and sorting**](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618) as well, **why not using it?**

if you still want to do everything manually, you can use something like

```
@{
    int iRow = 0;
}

@forach( var item in Model )
{
    iRow++;
    <div class="@( iRow % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd" )">
        @Model.SomeData @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeTextToType)
    </div>
}
```

---

**Updated**

the `WebGrid` helper just like it's cousin `gridview` in `webforms` is totally customizable, if you did `webforms` before, you know you could simple add a `templatecolumn` and append whatever 
controls you like, the `WebGrid` Helper is the same, for example as as stated in [**this fine article**](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/229962-mvc-3-webgrid-inside-a-webgrid/):

```
@grid.GetHtml(        
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(
             "Title", 
             "Movie", 
             @<text><div style='width: 10em'>@item.Title</div></text>), ...
```

Comment: Thanks for proposing alternatives... What would be the code for that case with the webgrid?

Comment: you have it in the link I posted about implementing pagging

Comment: Maybe it's me... I don't find it in the article (sample with editable data inside the grid, like a textbox).